# Deserialize JSON from a JSON array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson and I am trying to deserialize a JSON response that looks like the following:

```
{
    "Warnings": [{
            "Message": "Account code '48s9' has been removed as it does not match a recognised account"
        },
        {
            "Message": "Account code '48s9' has been removed as it does not match a recognised account"
        }
    ]
}
```

am I correct in saying that the class would look as follows? Is there some way this can be done?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class WarningsClass {

  private String Message;

  public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    Message = message;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't just try and see what will happens?

Answer (score 1):

was able to figure it out:

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
/* ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class); */
public class Warning{
    @JsonProperty("Message") 
    public String message;
}

public class WarningsClass{
    @JsonProperty("Warnings") 
    public List<Warning> warnings;
}


WarningsClass messageResponse = mapper.readValue(data, WarningsClass.class);
```

something like this would work